# $(this).nextAll("#...").eq(0).text("***") is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with `$(this).nextAll("#status").eq(0).text("Deleted")`.
I want to in the tag `<span>` put a text: "Deleted", but but does not insert it...
See the my code:

admin.php PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `upload_img`";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<div class='image' data-id='".$row['id']."'><br>";
            echo "<span><strong>Image title</strong>: ".$row['image_title']."</span><br>";
            echo "<span><strong>User of image</strong>: ".$row['user_name']."</span><br>";
            echo "<span><strong>Image file name</strong>: ".$row['image']."</span><br>";
            echo "<span id='status'></span>";
            echo "<button class='delete' data-id='".$row['id']."'>Delete</button><hr>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
```

admin.js JS:

```
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
var id = $(this).data("id");
$(this).nextAll("#status").eq(0).text("Deleted"); //This is not work!
$.post("adminServer.php", { id: id }, function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data);
});
```

});

I do not know why it does not work...
Thanks!

Comment: `id` attributes ***must be unique***. Change the `id="status"` to a class.

Comment: @KarloKokkak Nothing changed....

Comment: @Stupid can you provide sample html?

Comment: Also read up on what `nextAll()` does. It is not the proper traverse for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly part of your problem is that `id` attributes must be unique within the DOM. As such, only the first one will be recognised. You need to change the HTML generated to use a class on the `status` element instead:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `upload_img`";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<div class="image" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><br>';
  echo '<span><strong>Image title</strong>: '.$row['image_title'].'</span><br>';
  echo '<span><strong>User of image</strong>: '.$row['user_name'].'</span><br>';
  echo '<span><strong>Image file name</strong>: '.$row['image'].'</span><br>';
  echo '<span class="status"></span>'; // change the id to class here
  echo '<button class="delete" data-id="'.$row['id'].'">Delete</button><hr>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Secondly your DOM traversal logic isn't quite right. `nextAll()` goes through successive siblings, yet the `status` you're looking for is a preceding sibling. You can either use `prev()` or get the `closest()` parent, then `find()` within that. The latter is far more robust should you ever change the order of HTML elements. Also note that `eq(0)` is redundant as there's only one `status` generated per `.image` container.

```
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $(this).closest('div.image').find('.status').text("Deleted");

  $.post("adminServer.php", { id: id }, function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data); // don't use alert() for debugging.
  });
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Check below code with sample data. Hope it helps.

```
$(this).siblings(".status").eq(0).text("Deleted");
```

It gets nearby sibling with id status and update with status "Deleted"

```js
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $(this).siblings(".status").eq(0).text("Deleted");
  /*
   $.post("adminServer.php", { id: id }, function(data) {
       data = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log(data); // don't use alert() for debugging.
   });
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='image' data-id='1'>
 <br>
 <span><strong>Image title</strong>: Test1</span><br>
 <span><strong>User of image</strong>: Test1</span><br>
 <span><strong>Image file name</strong>: Test1</span><br>
 <span class='status'></span>
 <button class='delete' data-id='1'>Delete</button><hr>
</div>
<div class='image' data-id='2'>
 <br>
 <span><strong>Image title</strong>: Test2</span><br>
 <span><strong>User of image</strong>: Test2</span><br>
 <span><strong>Image file name</strong>: Test2</span><br>
 <span class='status'></span>
 <button class='delete' data-id='2'>Delete</button><hr>
</div>
<div class='image' data-id='3'>
 <br>
 <span><strong>Image title</strong>: Test3</span><br>
 <span><strong>User of image</strong>: Test3</span><br>
 <span><strong>Image file name</strong>: Test3</span><br>
 <span class='status'></span>
 <button class='delete' data-id='3'>Delete</button><hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine, but you haven't solved the major issue of duplicate `id` attributes in the DOM, you've just worked around it.